# Read any file with extension .txt inside a specified folder in ruby ​every 2 minutes

Tags: ruby

Every two minutes, I want to read all the files in a folder (for example `C:\folder\`) that have a `.txt` extension.

I do not know the names of each file because they are random.

After reading it would be convenient to delete the file to avoid overloading .

Does anyone know how this could be done?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Cada 2.minutos hacen `a = File.basename ("/folder/xxx.txt", ".txt") end´ ´File.foreach ('a.txt'). With_object ([]) do | line, result |´

Comment: Thank you I will keep it in mind for future questions. sorry @sawa

Comment: @sawa *tisk tisk*. In English we also use conjunctive adverbs and/or semicolons to separate clauses or emphasize relatedness. *"For your information, an English sentence starts with a capital letter **; therefore** no difference from Spanish."* :P

Comment: @sawa "4 u r 8" is English or not?

Comment: @engineersmnky No problem with that. But you shouldn't have a space before the semicolon. :)

Comment: @tadman I would call it Prince-ish.

Comment: @sawa I was unable to embolden the text without the space. Limitations of a markdown language I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
Dir.foreach('/path-to-your-files') do |item| 
  next unless File.extname(item) == '.txt'
  next if File.directory? item
  file = File.read(item)
  # do what you want with the file
  File.delete(item) if File.exist?(item)
end
```

As @engineersmnky says, you can simplify this a little using `Dir.glob`, as in:

```
Dir.glob('/path/to/files/*.txt') do
  # the rest, without the code to skip irrelevant files
end
```

That should do what you're after. Let me know how you get on!

---

Edit - to do this every two minutes, you'll have to use a reoccurring job. Sorry, slipped my mind when writing the question and I've got to go for now. Hopefully someone else'll cover this while I'm away, and I'll delete / update when I'm back online!

And to update upon this - the best way to get this running every two minutes will be to use a `cron` task, and the [whatever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem makes this a breeze. After setting it up, you can use, for example:

```
every 2.minutes do
  # run the code above
end
```

Comment: `Dir.glob('/path/to/files/*.txt')` might be a better choice as you can just pull the "txt" files

Comment: @JonathanZambrano - I've updated my answer with the scheduling every two minutes... hope it helps! enginerrsmnky - thanks, +1, will update my answer with that. I actually tried that first but me brain was a little shattered and it wasn't working locally. Will update above!

Comment: @SRack my friend had to format my computer and put the same code and now he says `No file or directory @ dir_initialize - / order_buy / lib / oc /`

Comment: @JonathanZambrano - do you know if the project's path has changed in some manner? Check the directory your code is in (try `pwd` in the terminal) and adjust this in your code to reflect this. Have a go at that and see if it helps :) Otherwise, I'd recommending starting a new question about the issue - that way you can give all the details and hopefully a nice, quick answer.

Comment: @SRack is very rare now says `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - abc.txt` but the file has that name but it does not open it. and I can not ask another question for 5 days.